# javafx is missing in the (select a wizard) window

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

My javafx applications run without any problems however the (select a wizard) window doesn't include javafx , what might be the reason for this and how can it be included?
I'm using eclipse 2021-12 and jdk (1.8)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What wizard are you asking about? I don't understand what you mean by "select a wizard"

Comment: it's the window which appears when following the steps : file-> new-> others or just by pressing ctrl+N I'm just wondering if it's important for javafx to be included there